# Is a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ "usable" enough for our coding/development, entertainment, gaming needs?

Tags: pi-3, performance

I'm planning on buying 2 units. One for myself for the purposes of learning web development, and one for my sister for entertainment purposes.

I know that the latest iteration of the device will enable me to use Chromium, node.js, Google's Polymer kit, GIMP, and even [a build](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://code.headmelted.com/&ved=2ahUKEwiHqeny1JfgAhXUEHIKHQp1ADsQFjAGegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw1G2Ekn-bpj7ChWFo4F2ThR) of Visual Studio Code, which I need to learn how to develop web apps.

As for my sister, she would like to use our dumb tv as a screen for playing Just Dance Now, an online game that is quite resource intensive (plays an HD video while showing real time scores accumulated from different devices). She would like to watch HD YouTube videos as well.

On paper, the Raspberry Pi 3 looks capable enough of handling all of these tasks without hiccups, but is that really the case? I think we may be better off buying a PC and/or a Chromecast for our needs, but we don't have the budget to buy those. We're not wanting or expecting cutting edge performance; we just need the Pi to get the job done, with few issues.

Edit: Trying to get your insights. Should I go for it, or save some money to buy a different device that will be capable enough to meet our demands?

Comment: then buy one ... or two ... the only way to find out if it's enough compute power for  your needs is to use it ...

Comment: My bad. See my edit.

Comment: the only way to find out if a Pi is suitable to **your requirements** is to buy one and find out ... a Pi can handle what you've written in the question ...

Comment: I agree with the above comments. Also, if they way you want to use video requires transcoding or other on-demand processing to play the video, or other CPU intensive activities, you may want to consider a different platform...but I would follow the above comments and try it first.

Comment: buy 1 for web dev.  try it for entertainment.  entertainment needs always expand (800x600@30FPS was great once upon a time) so when you realize it is not enough, get something else and use the one for just dev (and maybe running a personal/household server of some sort)

Answer (score -2):

It will meet your stated needs, at least for some level of performance that you may or may not find acceptable. It's a bit slow, but works ok.

It may not play that specific game your sister wants, and I think but am not sure that it will play HD youtube fine.

Since it will meet your stated needs, the easiest thing to do is to get one for you and see if it will work for her as well.